Patch call from another class
I have Processor class:
class Processor:
    def __init__(self, session_provider):
        self.session_provider = session_provider

    def  run(self):
        ...
        self.session_provider.get_session().stop()

I don't want session to be closed at the end of run method, but later. I tried to temporarily change it with patch:
import unittest
from unittest.mock import Mock, MagicMock, patch
from src.components.processor import Processor

class TestProcessor(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_run(self):
        ...
        with('src.components.processor.self.session_provider.get_session.stop', new_callable=Mock()):
            processor.run()

But I'm receiving error:
AttributeError: module 'src.components.processor' has no attribute 'self'

How can I fix this?

Why are you patching anything, when the dependency on session_provider is already inverted and you can trivially inject a test double?

Because it's a simple call of method in session_provider. I'm working on it's result  session_provider.get_session().stop(). What I need is temporary patching this path.

I've found that I need to patch the end call, not the nested path:
with patch('pyspark.sql.SparkSession.stop', new_callable = Mock()):
    ...
    processor.run()

